# How would you say: "This is my family photo taken two years ago of my younger brother's 10th birthday party."

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

I want to say

> This is a family photo taken two years ago of my younger brother's 10th birthday party.

I think I can break it up in separate sentences, e.g.
这是我全家的合影，是两年前拍了。我弟弟的十岁生日的时候。

But is there a way of saying it all in one sentence?

Here are my attempts:

> - 这(张)是我全家的合影，是两年前的弟弟的十岁生日时所拍了。
> - 这两年前的全家的合影，是我弟弟的十岁生日时所拍了。
> - 两年前的弟弟的十岁生日时，我们照了这张片，是我全家的合影。

Which one do you think makes the most sense? If they are incorrect, can you please provide a correction with an explanation?

多谢！

Comment: This is a concise way to express it: 这张全家福是两年前弟弟十岁生日时拍的。PS. 全家福 means 全家合影.

Comment: @dan this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 这(张)是我全家的合影，是两年前(的)弟弟(的)十岁生日时所拍的。

> 这两年前的全家的合影，是我弟弟(的)十岁生日时所拍的。

- Replace final particle 了 with 的. (的 serves as a pronoun particle for the object. Similar to 'which' in English)
- You should omit all the (的) in both sentences. They are not needed

Otherwise, they are grammatical, but you can rearrange the clauses in the first one to avoid using back to back 是. e.g. [It is X, it is Y] --> [It is XY] --> 这(张)是我全家两年前，弟弟十岁生日时所拍的合影照

> 两年前(的)弟弟(的)十岁生日时，我们照了这张照片，是我全家的合影。

- 照片 (photo) is not commonly shortened to 片.
- You should omit the (的) in this sentence too. They are not needed

Besides that, it is grammatical. You can reduce it to "两年前弟弟十岁生日时，我们照了这张全家的合影照。" to make it shorter.

合影照 short for 合影的照片

Answer (score 6):

我认为这样就可以了

> 这张全家福是两年前在我弟弟十岁生日聚会时拍的。